# file_get_contents ported from drupal_http_request

Tags: php, drupal

I need a bit of help porting a function over from the drupal code.

I have found out that drupal_http_request is basically file_get_contents, but when i change it, i seem to be getting errors,

The original drupal code is as follows:

```
$response = drupal_http_request($url, array('Content-Type' => 'text/xml'), 'POST', $post_data);
```

Basically all im doing is replacing it so it looks like so

```
$response = file_get_contents($url, array('Content-Type' => 'text/xml'), 'POST', $post_data);
```

When i run this though ... i get the following error message

```
file_get_contents() expects parameter 2 to be boolean
```

Im wondering if anyone can help me port it over.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents` does not take array as second argument see http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php for detail examples

```
$opts = array (
        'http' => array (
                'method' => "POST",
                'header' => 'Content-Type: text/xml\r\n',
                'content' => $post_data 
        ) 
);
$context = stream_context_create ( $opts );
$data = file_get_contents ( $url, false, $context );
```